# Suggestion on buying a single speed 29er mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, product-rec, single-speed

I'm interested in buying a single speed mountain bike for about $400-600. Can anyone recommend me one?

I tried buying this http://www.redlinebicycles.com/bikes/mtb/2012-monocog-29er but it is all sold out. I'm 5'6" so I need a small frame for a 29er. I would like the bike to be in a darker color like in the link if possible. Nothing like white or bright colors on the bike as it's main color.

Comment: Even a single speed bike of any quality will cost a fair bit more than that budget. I realize that's not the answer you want, and I'll not post it as an answer. But I will recommend that you take the time to save a little more cash. There is definitely a law of diminishing returns when it comes to bike pricing, but it doesn't really start to matter until about $1500 dollars or so. For a single speed, something between 500 and 800 dollars will hit the sweet spot between quality and price. You won't regret saving longer for a better bike. You might regret buying early and cheap.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta pay more for fewer gears.

Comment: Unfortunately this sold out by the time I decided to get it. I have now committed to buying a single speed after doing a lot of research and consulting with a friend. I went to a few bike shops to find that monocog bike but unfortunately these bikes are kind of rare and hard to find at my height.

Answer (score 4):

SE Stout is a single speed mountain bike that runs relatively cheap.

If you're confident in your ability to put it together properly, you can find them at bikesdirect for around 350. 
http://www.bikesdirect.com/products/se/stout.htm

It's got tabs for disc brakes so you could upgrade in the future, but comes with V-Brakes stock.  I have a few friends who have these bikes and really like them.

Comment: When you mean by putting it together myself, do I have to buy the parts seperately or do they all come together in a box? Also looking at the price, it's above 300. I'll have to think about that (not out of the question) but is there anything < 300?

Comment: All the parts should come with it in the box.

I purchased 2 single speed track bikes from bikesdirect and assembled them myself. There are no instructions.

You can probably purchase this bike assembled from a bike shop for a bit more.  Some bike shops do get kind of 'touchy' about people who buy bikes online, can't put them together and then pay them to assemble.  If you're not confident that you can put it together properly then ask your local bike shop what kind of price they can get this bike to you for.

Comment: Ah ok that's cool, I have a friend that's into building bikes so I can ask him for help, thanks.

Comment: or this has a few better parts than the SE: http://www.bikesdirect.com/products/dawes/bullseye.htm

Comment: Awesome Matt, I'm definitely getting it once I get home (if the 5'6" isn't sold out by than, lol)

Answer (score 0):

You can generally find a great deal on a used single speed 29er. Everyone likes to try it, few stick with it. Or with your busget, they find they love it, and upgrade selling their "starter" SS 29er.

Try your local Craigslist.org, MTBR.com and ebay.com  for deals on used.

Comment: I have used and will continue to use all three for the foreseeable future, just bought a 29er 1x9 on CL this weekend and got a great deal